# FileNotFoundException on tmp/roth_sentences.ser when training Stanford Relation Extractor model

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm trying to train my own relation extraction model as described [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/relationExtractor.html#training) but keep getting a strange error.

My properties file:

```
#Below are some basic options. See edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.MachineReadingProperties class for more options.

# Pipeline options
annotators = pos, lemma, parse
parse.maxlen = 100

# MachineReading properties. You need one class to read the dataset into correct format. See edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.domains.ace.AceReader for another example.
datasetReaderClass = edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.domains.roth.RothCONLL04Reader

readerLogLevel = INFO
#Data directory for training. The datasetReaderClass reads data from this path and makes corresponding sentences and annotations.
trainPath = ../re-training-data.corp

#Whether to crossValidate, that is evaluate, or just train.
crossValidate = false
kfold = 10

#Change this to true if you want to use CoreNLP pipeline generated NER tags. The default model generated with the relation extractor release uses the CoreNLP pipeline provided tags (option set to true$
trainUsePipelineNER=true

# where to save training sentences. uses the file if it exists, otherwise creates it.
serializedTrainingSentencesPath = tmp/roth_sentences.ser

serializedEntityExtractorPath = tmp/roth_entity_model.ser

# where to store the output of the extractor (sentence objects with relations generated by the model). This is what you will use as the model when using 'relation' annotator in the CoreNLP pipeline.
serializedRelationExtractorPath = tmp/kpl-relation-model-pipeline.ser

# uncomment to load a serialized model instead of retraining
# loadModel = true

#relationResultsPrinters = edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.RelationExtractorResultsPrinter,edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.domains.roth.RothResultsByRelation. For printing output of the model.
relationResultsPrinters = edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.RelationExtractorResultsPrinter

#In this domain, this is trivial since all the entities are given (or set using CoreNLP NER tagger).
entityClassifier = edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.domains.roth.RothEntityExtractor

extractRelations = true
extractEvents = false

#We are setting the entities beforehand so the model does not learn how to extract entities etc.
extractEntities = false

#Opposite of crossValidate.
trainOnly=true

# The set chosen by feature selection using RothCONLL04:
relationFeatures = arg_words,arg_type,dependency_path_lowlevel,dependency_path_words,surface_path_POS,entities_between_args,full_tree_path
```

Here's what I run in the terminal:

```
sudo java -cp stanford-corenlp-3.7.0.jar:stanford-corenlp-3.7.0-models.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.MachineReading --arguments kpl-re-model.properties
```

And the the result:

```
PERCENTAGE OF TRAIN: 1.0
The reader log level is set to INFO
Adding annotator pos
Loading POS tagger from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger ... done [0.8 sec].
Adding annotator lemma
Adding annotator parse
Loading parser from serialized file edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz ... done [0.6 sec].
Jan 17, 2017 4:55:06 PM edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.MachineReading makeResultsPrinters
INFO: Making result printers from 
Jan 17, 2017 4:55:06 PM edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.MachineReading makeResultsPrinters
INFO: Making result printers from edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.RelationExtractorResultsPrinter
Jan 17, 2017 4:55:06 PM edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.MachineReading makeResultsPrinters
INFO: Making result printers from 
Jan 17, 2017 4:55:06 PM edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.MachineReading loadOrMakeSerializedSentences
INFO: Parsing corpus sentences...
Jan 17, 2017 4:55:06 PM edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.MachineReading loadOrMakeSerializedSentences
INFO: These sentences will be serialized to /home/ubuntu/stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31/tmp/roth_sentences.ser
Jan 17, 2017 4:55:06 PM edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.domains.roth.RothCONLL04Reader read
INFO: Reading file: ../re-training-data.corp
Jan 17, 2017 4:55:07 PM edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.GenericDataSetReader preProcessSentences
SEVERE: GenericDataSetReader: Started pre-processing the corpus...
Jan 17, 2017 4:55:07 PM edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.GenericDataSetReader preProcessSentences
INFO: Annotating dataset with edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP@5f9d02cb
Jan 17, 2017 4:58:32 PM edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.GenericDataSetReader preProcessSentences
SEVERE: GenericDataSetReader: Pre-processing complete.
Jan 17, 2017 4:58:32 PM edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.GenericDataSetReader parse
SEVERE: Changing NER tags using the CoreNLP pipeline.
Replacing old annotator "parse" with signature [edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.ParserAnnotator#parse.maxlen:100;#] with new annotator with signature [edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.ParserAnnotator##]
Adding annotator pos
Adding annotator lemma
Adding annotator ner
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [1.4 sec].
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [0.5 sec].
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [0.5 sec].
Jan 17, 2017 4:58:45 PM edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.MachineReading loadOrMakeSerializedSentences
INFO: Done. Parsed 1183 sentences.
Jan 17, 2017 4:58:45 PM edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.MachineReading loadOrMakeSerializedSentences
INFO: Serializing parsed sentences to /home/ubuntu/stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31/tmp/roth_sentences.ser...
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: tmp/roth_sentences.ser (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.writeObjectToFile(IOUtils.java:77)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.writeObjectToFile(IOUtils.java:63)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.MachineReading.loadOrMakeSerializedSentences(MachineReading.java:914)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.MachineReading.run(MachineReading.java:270)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.MachineReading.main(MachineReading.java:111
```

The error states that it can't find 'tmp/roth_sentences.ser' but it doesn't make sense because it's supposed to *create* that file.

Any ideas?

Thanks!
Simon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you change `tmp/roth_sentences.ser` to `roth_sentences.ser` it should work.  I'm guessing the issue is `/home/ubuntu/stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31/tmp` doesn't exist, so when it tries to write the file it crashes.

Comment: It worked! How strange, before posting this question I had the same suspicion so I tried _creating_ a tmp directory, but that didn't work. Anyway, thank you!